# Avoid product join in teradata in sql

Tags: sql, teradata, cpu-usage, memory-efficient, sql-optimization

I have below query in tera data which seems to be taking lot of CPU utilization, i am looking for some more alternatives to achieve the same in an efficient way. Please let me know if you have any thoughts

```
 CREATE TABLE users AS (
 SELECT a.*, b.col1, b.col2, b.col3, b.col4
    FROM (SEL col1, col2, col3 AS c_id, id , col4, flight_id
    FROM t1
    WHERE flight_id IN (1234, 5678, 8910, 3456, 1265, 9876, 6544, 4321) 
    AND ym <> '201501') a
    LEFT JOIN t2 b
    ON a.c_id = b.customer_id)
WITH DATA
PRIMARY INDEX(id);
```

Now the no. of records in t1(with where conditions no of rows) and t2 are **17,000,000** and **1,055,123,456** respectively. The query took approx 10 mins but more challenge is it takes lot of CPU usage, I understand its because of product join that is being done. but i am not getting how to handle it by different way. Any inputs are much appreciated.

As per suggestion, i have updated the query as shown below and i got quite better performance almost query time has been reduced to half. I have only one concern now i am getting message from TeraData Prod team which says my query is inefficient in terms of Inefficiency is expressed by the amount of CPU the system uses per I/O. I am not able to understand how i can make it efficient for it as i have such a huge dataset ?

```
CREATE TABLE users AS (
SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.c_id , a.id, a.col4, a.flight_id, b.col1, b.col2, 
 b.col3, b.col4 
FROM t1 a
LEFT JOIN t2 b
ON a.c_id = b.customer_id
WHERE flight_id IN (1234, 5678, 8910, 3456, 1265, 9876, 6544, 4321) AND ym 
 <> '201501' a)
WITH DATA
PRIMARY INDEX(id);
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Teradata? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Can you show Explain? What's the maximum number of rows per `id`? If it's high switching to a `MultiSet` table might help. Do you have access to the QueryLog to get the actual resource usage by step?

Comment: As dnoeth suggests, the high cpu is probably more to due with using the default SET table as opposed to a MULTISET table in your CREATE TABLE statement. SET tables cause every record inserted to do a duplicate row check on existing data in the table. After a hundred thousand rows are inserted already, this can be very taxing. Perhaps, though, take your SELECT statement out of the CREATE TABLE statement and see what it's performance is like all by itself. If it's also a terror then you can also tune the SELECT itself.

Comment: I can't see a product join. Why using a select from subselect and not doing it in one step? Maybe the optimizer would choose a better plan. I assume the time consuming is due to necessary redistribution of data. If t1.c_id and t2.customer_id are not Primary index in both tables, redistribution is necessary for doing the join. Maybe a secondary index could help. Or a join index with partial coverage could be worth the effort, dependig on your situation. Putting the resulting data into the target table with a different Primary index, again needs redistribution. Target table as nonPI?

Comment: Thanks ULick, JNevil by removing select from subselect i got some imporovement in performance .. Also as suggested will try to see possiblities with secondary index.